# Redirect all incoming domain variations to an absolute domain Heroku Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, dns

My setup is:
- Heroku
- Rails 3
- GoDaddy DNS

I'm trying to redirect all incoming routes of a domain variation to an absolute path. Including HTTPS.

For example:

```
algrim.co
www.algrim.co
http://www.algrim.co
http://algrim.co
```

Should all redirect to:

```
https://www.algrim.co
```

Heroku wants the application to do this. All I've tried within the application controller is this
  before_filter :correct_domain!

```
def correct_domain!
if request.host == "https://algrim.co"
  redirect_to "https://www.algrim.co#{request.fullpath}", :status => 301
end
```

end

But it doesn't cover all of the cases. Can someone help me here. How do I ensure all links pointing to my site are going to the correct places.

Comment: Your filter is good. Why not just try to match request.host to the correct host and if it doesn't match redirect?